# Using CLT to define normal distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

While reading the statement for the Central Limit Theorem on Wikipedia, I began wondering if the following "definition" for "normal distribution" makes sense in the context of real, continuous random variables. Would appreciate a review of my suggested "definition", and help if it is inaccurate:

> Suppose all random variables here are real, continuous, from the same probability space, and have finite mean and finite variance. If $\{X_n\}$ is a sequence of arbitrarily chosen, independent and identically distributed random variables, each having mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then it follows from the Central Limit Theorem that $$\frac{\sqrt n}{\sigma}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i  -\mu\right)$$ converges in distribution to some random variable $Z$ as $n \rightarrow +\infty$. Any such $Z$ is observed to have mean $0$ and variance $1$, and is said to have the *standard normal distribution*.

> Further, any random variable $Y$ of the form $\sigma_Y Z + \mu_Y$, where $\mu_Y$ and $\sigma_Y$ are real numbers, and where $Z$ has the standard normal distribution, is said to have a *normal distribution*.

Comment: At first sight, it looks okay to me, but we may encounter the problem of circular reasoning since the proofs of CLT I am aware of depend on the definition of normal distribution.

Comment: $Y_0$ only has a *standard* normal distribution if its mean is $0$ and variance is $1$.  If that is what you want your term to converge to in distribution, then you need to divide it by $\sigma$.

Comment: You might also adjust your labels: having $Y_0$ and $Z$ as standard normal random variables but $Y$ more general seems likely to confuse.

Comment: @Henry Fixed the definition for standard normal distribution and simplified the notation. Meanwhile I wonder if “every sequence” can be replaced with “some sequence” in the definition of standard normal distribution, thereby reducing the unnecessary strictness in the definition. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Sure, you could do any given iid sequence with finite second moment. It doesn't matter, really (in either case you need to prove the CLT to show that this definition is consistent). Also re:circularity one could show that such a sum converges to *something* and define that *something* as standard normal, but I don't see a technical or pedagogical advantage per-se.

Comment: The $X_i$s are i.i.d. (with finite variance) so perhaps you could say "a sequence" if you prefer.  Since this is convergence in distribution, it is a statement of the distribution of the random variables made up of such sums (with the indicated relocation and rescaling)  rather than a statement about a particular sequence of values.

Comment: Understood, @daisies. As for the pedagogical advantage, I thought my proposed definition had one: the proposed definition is based on the idea of convergence and therefore sounds more "interesting" (or offers deeper insight) that the routine definition ("algebraic expression") as stated on the Wikipedia page for Normal distribution.

Comment: Understood, @Henry. Have updated the problem statement suitably.

Comment: What extra insight do we gain by making  the CLT an axiom? Insights don't come for free.

Comment: @KurtG.: The insight to gain here (if my understanding is correct) is that standard normal distribution gets identified with the sum of a series built using an arbitrary sequence of i.i.d. random variables (with finite mean, variance). I guess it is this insight (or some such insight, say related to "entropy") that historically led to the discovery of the "algebraic formula" for normal distribution, rather than the other way around. Perhaps what I am suggesting here is already well known to be a fact (or a misunderstanding), but I found it more interesting than the "algebraic formula".

Comment: You may want to elaborate how entropy historically led to the discovery of the normal distributiion. Perhaps this gives me some new insight. The CLT is a remarkable theorem that shows how ubiquitous the normal distribution is. That its PDF has a nice formula is even hetter. You prefer that new definition to provide insight *gain*. I don't. Without the CLT as a *theorem* we both would not have that insight.

Comment: @KurtG., I don’t understand much about the entropy of a random variable. Nevertheless, quoting for reference directly from   https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution as follows: The normal distribution has maximum entropy … among all real-valued distributions … with a specified variance … .

Comment: That's right and is another remarkable property of the normal distribution. I believe the normal distribution was discovered by de Moivre when he looked at outcomes of coin tosses for a large number of tries. He found that the normal approximates probabilities well. We can safely say that the normal distribution was discovered *because* of the CLT.